# Guardar la propiedad de un JSON en una variable Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs

Tengo este JSON

```
    {
    "user": "user0001",
    "pass": "pass0001",
    "toke": "asdqwe1234",
    "json":[{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        },
          {
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 2,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        }
]
},
{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 2,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Mail": "mail@dominio.com",
                "Copy": "copy@dominio.com",
                "ccd": "cdd@dominio.com"
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message",
                "Image": "URL",
                "File": "URL"
            }
        },
        {
            "Channel": 2,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Mail": "mail@dominio.com",
                "Copy": "copy@dominio.com",
                "ccd": "cdd@dominio.com"
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message",
                "Image": "URL",
                "File": "URL"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
}
```

Y me gustaria guardar la propiedad "json" en una variable algo asi:

```
    var jsonFile = [{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        },
          {
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 2,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        }
]
},
{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 2,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Mail": "mail@dominio.com",
                "Copy": "copy@dominio.com",
                "ccd": "cdd@dominio.com"
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message",
                "Image": "URL",
                "File": "URL"
            }
        },
        {
            "Channel": 2,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Mail": "mail@dominio.com",
                "Copy": "copy@dominio.com",
                "ccd": "cdd@dominio.com"
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message",
                "Image": "URL",
                "File": "URL"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```js
var jsonOriginal = {
    "user": "user0001",
    "pass": "pass0001",
    "toke": "asdqwe1234",
    "json":[{
    "Notification": [{
            "Channel": 1,
            "Type": 1,
            "Means": [{
                "Number": 88888888,
                "Code": 506
            }],
            "Contents": {
                "Message": "This is a message"
            }
        }
]
}]
};

var jsonFile = jsonOriginal.json[0]; // 0 es la prosición en la que se encuentra "Notification". 

console.log(jsonFile);
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias! Disculpa y si fueran multiples notificaciones? 

Para que te hagas una idea modifique la pregunta :)

Comment: En ese caso únicamente haz lo siguiente: `var jsonFile = jsonOriginal.json`. La variable jsonFile te traería un array con todas las notificaciones. Saludos!